# Eclipse Kepler/PyDev not showing any errors

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, eclipse-kepler

I am using Eclipse Kepler with PyDev and initially it was giving me errors for all of my local imports (imports from the same project that weren't in the same folder) so I removed the PyDev configuration and then added it back and now it isn't giving me errors for anything but indentation errors.  Any idea what to do here?

Or how to solve the initial problem?